# Storing Transglutaminase once opened

Tags: storage-method, chemistry, molecular-gastronomy

I have a sealed packet of Transglutaminase/Activa powder. However its much more than I need for this recipe. I know it deactivates quickly after being exposed to air. Whats the best way to store it for future use? Should I keep it as one mass of powder or split it into smaller packages?

Answer (score 2):

"Transglutaminase should be stored in the freezer at all times. This will prevent the enzyme from becoming inactive"
According to
https://blog.modernistpantry.com/advice/troubleshooting-transglutaminase/

Answering this because I was about to ask about storage myself.

Still would like to know if freezer extends shelf life long enough to warrant commercial quantities ie 1kg = year supply for  me.

Would vacuum sealing smaller quantities make any difference beyond freezing?

Comment: I had a look at laboratory supplier sites for stability at -20, but all the information supplied was only "store at -20". Given this it is likely that it would last at least ~6 mo at that temp. It is almost always better not to freeze-thaw enzymes, so aliquoting into smaller packets would be better.  Your best bet is to buy a bunch and test how long it lasts.